# SSRS : Overlapping Line in Line Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, linechart

I have created a line chart which has the date as X-axis and Y-axis as calculated median value and its grouped according to "FileName". Problem is that some of the "FileName" has same median values which makes line overlap thus not able to see all the lines. Attached image shows only 5 lines but there are total 10 lines. After running query I found out other 5 has 50 as the median which makes it overlap with one of the line. [image: Line Chart]

I tried using transparency and secondary axis but wasn't able to achieve the desired result. Is there any other solution to try out ? Thanks!

Comment: You may need to change the chart type. if 5 lines are overlapping each other, how can you show that in a line chart?

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to check whether there is anything else that I haven't explored to make it visible.

Comment: Fingers crossed and wait for the **GURUS** to step in :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a data presentation issue than something specific to SSRS.  If you are stuck on using a line chart, then I've only used two options:

1) Increment lines to different widths.  For example, in a chart with 3 lines, the width is set to 5,3,1 pts.

2) Change the values insignificantly to offset the lines.  Obviously this depends on the data being visualized as shifting the line slight (multiply by 0.1) may be allowable or highly discouraged depending on your situation.

Trying to do either option with 10 lines (and up to 5+ stacking) is not going to be very good.

I think Viking is right and you might want to check out other visualization options.  Grouped column charts perhaps or just split your chart into multiple charts on the page (i.e. four separate trend charts)

Comment: Ok..I will try to use some different chart